# vertical lines in svg path don't show

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm attempting some basic svg animation and I'm having trouble drawing a simple polygon using . For some reason, the vertical lines of my shape don't show.

Here's my code:

```css
.path {
  fill: red;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path class="path" d="M160,60 L-160,60 l0,-60 z">
</svg>
```

And here's the result I'm getting: [bad shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8ev3.png)

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks to me like it's simply the position of the shape, I think the negative values are taking it out of the view of its bounding box, therefore you aren't actually seeing the left side of the triangle.

Comment: If you aren't already familiar with it, you can right click a web page and select 'inspect' to see details of the live content. Inspecting your polygon does indeed show it is outside of your viewable area, thus not showing the left side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line is outside of viewport. You could change [viewBox](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) attribute value or replace your shape to the right. See working example below.

```css
.path {
  fill: red;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-200 -10 400 80">
  <path class="path" d="M160,60 L-160,60 l0,-60 z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Now it's show the whole shape, which is great, but it's scaled way up. How did you determine the viewBox values?

Comment: @cyang2 , look at the path values of your SVG. The path starts from point _x=160, y=60_ (see `M160,60`). Then you draw line to point _x=-160, y=0_ (see `L-160,60`). The next segment `l0,-60` draws line that's width equals to _0_ and height is equal to _-60_ (relative coordinates). `z` closes circuit. Thus, the minimum _x_ value equals to _-160_, minimum y value equals to _0_, width is _- 320_, height is _60_. I increase the modules of this values to fit shape to the vieport. Use [preserveAspectRatio](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) to force uniform scaling.

Comment: @cyang2, is your question solved? Do you need additional explanation?

Comment: yes, my question is solved. thanks so much for the help!